# How to add a QDockWidget to QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt4

Is it possible to add a DockWidget to my QGraphicsScene scene .? If yes how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I see to achieve this would be to create a [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmainwindow.html), set your graphicsScene as the central widget with

```
QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(QWidget* widget);
```

After that, simply add your QDockWidget in the QMainWindow with

```
QMainWindow::addDockWidget(Qt::DockWidgetArea area, QDockWidget* dockwidget);
```

This option also allows you to add toolbar(s) or menu(s) easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your response. But the problem is that I don't have a QMainWindow, I just have a scene. How to do it?

Comment: In the Qt documentation, you cannot create a QDockWidget in anything else than a QMainWindow. There is other solutions that are possible: a QSplitter with your scene on one side and your dock widget on the other side, or simply a layout. But, I do not see how you could use the functionnalities of QDockWidget without a QMainWindow. Create a QMainWindow is not complicated and it can have pretty much the same look and fell than a default window. I _think_ that QApplication creates a main window on its own if you don't create one. Ask if you need help to customize a QMainWindow. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll check if this is possible in  my case.